# ¿Consulta where sqlite dos campos?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

¿Como puedo hacer una consulta `sqlite` con where con dos campos? Algo similar al siguiente código:

```
select * from tabla where cap1=1 and cap2=2;
```

Se que tengo que pasarle argmentos, pero no se como armar toda la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Android usando SQLite puedes usar esta forma:

```
 Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE cap1 = ? AND cap2= ?", new String[] {"1", "2"});
```

Usando [rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])), defines el Query y los argumentos de selección en un array de strings.

```
rawQuery(String sqlQuery, String[] selectionArgs)
```